# how to xshift tikzmark and preserve interrow spacing in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, matrices, tikzmark

I am trying to use the `\tikzmark` command to overlay a right brace with a label next to a `pmatrix`. Unfortunately, there are two problems with the current output:

1. My code has introduced extra vertical space between rows in the matrix. How do I fix this?
2. I want to shift the brace to the right by a few mm. How do I do this?

My code and output are shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmarkeast[2][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.east)]
\node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0](#1){#2};}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & 1 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 \\
  & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma_1^0 \\ \gamma_1^1 \\ \gamma_1^2 \\
  \gamma_2^0 \\ \gamma_2^1 \\ \gamma_2^2 \\
  \gamma_3^0 \\ \gamma_3^1 \\ \gamma_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
\leq
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \tikzmarkeast[select-1]{1} \\ 1 \\ \tikzmarkeast[select-2]{1} \\
    1 \\ 1 \\
    L
  \end{pmatrix}
%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt},xshift=6mm]
  (select-1.north east)
  -- node[right=3pt]{$\sum \gamma_t^k \leq 1$}
  (select-2.south east);
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is `baseline=(#1.east)`. It should be `baseline=(#1.base)`. Further, you can put `xshift` inside the coordinates like

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt},]
  ([xshift=6mm]select-1.north east)
  -- node[right=3pt]{$\sum \gamma_t^k \leq 1$}
  ([xshift=6mm]select-2.south east);
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\tikzmarkeast[2][]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]\node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0](#1){#2};}%

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & 1 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 \\
  & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma_1^0 \\ \gamma_1^1 \\ \gamma_1^2 \\
  \gamma_2^0 \\ \gamma_2^1 \\ \gamma_2^2 \\
  \gamma_3^0 \\ \gamma_3^1 \\ \gamma_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
\leq
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \tikzmarkeast[select-1]{1} \\
     1 \\ \tikzmarkeast[select-2]{1} \\
    1 \\ 1 \\
    L
  \end{pmatrix}
%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt},]
  ([xshift=6mm]select-1.north east)
  -- node[right=3pt]{$\sum \gamma_t^k \leq 1$}
  ([xshift=6mm]select-2.south east);
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]